# TensorFlow: questions regarding tf.argmax() and tf.equal()

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am learning the TensorFlow, building a multilayer_perceptron model. I am looking into some examples like the one at: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.ipynb

I then have some questions in the code below:

```
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    :
    :

pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)
    :
    :

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
         :
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    print ("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: X_test, y: y_test_onehot}))
```

I am wondering what do `tf.argmax(prod,1)` and `tf.argmax(y,1)` mean and return (type and value) exactly? And is `correct_prediction` a variable instead of real values?

Finally, how do we get the `y_test_prediction` array (the prediction result when the input data is `X_test`) from the tf session? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 56):

```
tf.argmax(input, axis=None, name=None, dimension=None)
```

Returns the index with the largest value across axis of a tensor.

input is a Tensor and axis describes which axis of the input Tensor to reduce across. For vectors, use axis = 0.

For your specific case let's use two arrays and demonstrate this

```
pred = np.array([[31, 23,  4, 24, 27, 34],
                [18,  3, 25,  0,  6, 35],
                [28, 14, 33, 22, 20,  8],
                [13, 30, 21, 19,  7,  9],
                [16,  1, 26, 32,  2, 29],
                [17, 12,  5, 11, 10, 15]])

y = np.array([[31, 23,  4, 24, 27, 34],
                [18,  3, 25,  0,  6, 35],
                [28, 14, 33, 22, 20,  8],
                [13, 30, 21, 19,  7,  9],
                [16,  1, 26, 32,  2, 29],
                [17, 12,  5, 11, 10, 15]])
```

Evaluating `tf.argmax(pred, 1)` gives a tensor whose evaluation will give `array([5, 5, 2, 1, 3, 0])`

Evaluating `tf.argmax(y, 1)` gives a tensor whose evaluation will give `array([5, 5, 2, 1, 3, 0])`

```
tf.equal(x, y, name=None) takes two tensors(x and y) as inputs and returns the truth value of (x == y) element-wise.
```

Following our example, `tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1),tf.argmax(y, 1))` returns a tensor whose evaluation will give`array(1,1,1,1,1,1)`.

correct_prediction is a tensor whose evaluation will give a 1-D array of 0's and 1's

y_test_prediction can be obtained by executing `pred = tf.argmax(logits, 1)`

The documentation for tf.argmax and tf.equal can be accessed by following the links below.

tf.argmax() https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/sequence_comparison_and_indexing#argmax

tf.equal() https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/comparison_operators#equal

Comment: Does the `logits` is the `pred` in that code ? I mean logits is the result of a model, for example `out = tf.matmul(fully_conn_layer, _weights['out']) + _biases['out']` (I have a CNN implement AlexNet model) ?
So I don't understand how you obtain `pred = tf.argmax(logits, 1)`

Comment: because in this case, logits are probabilities (for each class) that a "sample/picture" belongs to.
So in order to get the pred. for a "sample/picture", you get the maximum probability, thus you use tf.argmax

Answer (score 17):

Reading the documentation:

[`tf.argmax`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argmax)

> Returns the index with the largest value across axes of a tensor.

[`tf.equal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/equal)

> Returns the truth value of (x == y) element-wise.

[`tf.cast`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cast)

> Casts a tensor to a new type.

[`tf.reduce_mean`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_mean)

> Computes the mean of elements across dimensions of a tensor.

---

Now you can easily explain what it does. Your `y` is one-hot encoded, so it has one 1 and all other are zero. Your `pred` represents probabilities of classes. So argmax finds the positions of best prediction and correct value. After that you check whether they are the same.

So now your `correct_prediction` is a vector of True/False values with the size equal to the number of instances you want to predict. You convert it to floats and take the average.

---

Actually this part is nicely explained in [TF tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) in the **Evaluate the Model** part

Comment: in a real model this process, I mean the process of tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1)) is done for each sample or each batch or each epoch? what the final value will be?

Answer (score 2):

**tf.argmax(input, axis=None, name=None, dimension=None)**

> Returns the index with the largest value across axis of a tensor.

For the case in specific, it receives `pred` as argument for it's `input` and `1` as `axis`. The axis describes which axis of the input Tensor to reduce across. For vectors, use axis = 0.

Example: Given the list `[2.11,1.0021,3.99,4.32]` argmax will return `3` which is the index of the highest value.

---

**correct_prediction** is a tensor that will be evaluated later. It is not a regular python variable. It contains the necessary information to compute the value later.
For this specific case, it will be part of another tensor `accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))` and will be evaluated by `eval` on `accuracy.eval({x: X_test, y: y_test_onehot})`.

---

**y_test_prediction** should be your `correct_prediction` tensor.

Comment: why it will return `3` ? where largest value is 4.32 ?

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul The index of 4.32, the highest value, is 3. It starts from 0 (2.11)

Comment: Got it , it return index instead of value.

Answer (score 1):

For those who do not have much time to understand **tf.argmax**:

x = np.array([[1, 9, 3],[4, 5, 6]])

**tf.argmax(x, axis = 0)**

output:

```
[array([1, 0, 1], dtype=int64)]
```

**tf.argmax(x, axis = 1)**

Output:

```
[array([1, 2], dtype=int64)]
```

[image]

[source](https://www.tutorialexample.com/understand-tensorflow-tf-argmax-and-axis-for-beginners-tensorflow-tutorial/)